# Coloring labels and lines in a dendrogram plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, dendrogram

I want to change the color of lines in the dendrogram corresponding to its label. However, I haven't seen anything like that before. So I want to at least change the color of the text labels.

Comment: Please clarify your question with your exact need, preferably with an illustration of the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is no simple solution for that. The labels of the dendrogram are simply the y-axis tick labels and are all sharing the same `color` property. On the other hand, the lines are not constructed in sets, so all the lines connecting between to adjacent nodes are one object. The following example illustrates all that:

[image: color dend]

now the question is what is your specific purpose regarding the lines to color? mainly, what would you like to do with the vertical lines?

---

## Coloring the lables

The idea in this woraround is to replace all the lables by text, so they could be colored saparetly:

```
ax = gca; % get the axes handle
lab = ax.YAxis.TickLabels; % get all the labels
loc = ax.YAxis.TickValues; % get all labels location
[ulab,~,lab_ind] = unique(lab); % find all unique labels
clr = lines(numel(ulab)); % make a color map
for k = 1:numel(ulab) % for every type of lable
    ind = strcmp(ulab{k},lab); % find all instances in lab
    x = repelem(ax.XAxis.Limits(1)-0.01,sum(ind)); % make an x position vector
     % place this lable at the same locations with a distinct color:
    text(x,loc(ind),lab(ind),'Color',clr(k,:));
end
ax.YAxis.TickLabels = []; % remove the original labels
% replace the original labels with white space, to keep the axes position:
ax.YAxis.TickLabels = repelem('  ',max(cellfun(@numel,lab)));
```

[image: color dend lables]

---

## Coloring first level lines

The idea here is similar - to place a line with the same color of the label above the current line. The nodes will be treated later.

First, we have to collect all the coordinates data from the figure:

```
ax = gca; % get the axes handle
X = get(ax.Children,'XData'); % Get x values of all lines
Y = get(ax.Children,'YData'); % Get y values of all lines
```

this has to be done before adding the colored labels (if you choose to do that too), so you won't get an error.

Then, we can loop through the lines and color them if they are placed at the y-axis ticks value (i.e. they have an integer y data). Recall (and look at the [picture above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrER6.png) for a reminder) that each `line` object is essentially 3 connected lines, so we want to look only at the first and last line:

```
for k = 1:numel(Y)
    if Y{k}(1)==fix(Y{k}(1))
        line(ax,X{k}(1:2),Y{k}(1:2),'Color',clr(lab_ind(Y{k}(1)),:),...
            'LineWidth',2);
    end
    if Y{k}(3)==fix(Y{k}(3))
        line(ax,X{k}(3:4),Y{k}(3:4),'Color',clr(lab_ind(Y{k}(3)),:),...
            'LineWidth',2);
    end
end
```

`clr` and `lab_ind` are taken from the code above (for the labels), and I made the line a little thicker only for clarity.

The result will be:

[image: color dend 2]

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much and coloring label is what I am looking for. I wonder is it possible to let the lines have same color as its' label?

Comment: @Excalibur as  I wrote above, you'll have to define more strictly what do you mean by coloring the lines, the best will be to provide some example (drawn manualy) the illustrates your idea. Anyway, it will be more complicated then coloring the labels.

Comment: For example, if in you second figure, the first three lines would be orange; forth line blue; fifth yellow; sixth purple and so on. If two line have same color merge together, then the line after merge keep that color. if two line have different colors, then the line after merge will be black. Thanks again!

Comment: @Excalibur, working on that. Can you please add the detailed description to your question, so it will be understandable without reading the comments here?

Comment: @Excalibur see my edit for the 'low' level lines, I'll add the rest, but only if you will edit your question to be clear and detailed.

Comment: Thank you! This is so helpful!