# Simple coloring of Scipy dendrograms

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to create a monochrome (eg., black on white) dendrogram using Scipy. After the Scipy documentation, I have been playing with the set_link_color_pallete function, but kept getting just one of the groups in black, while the remaining of the dendrogram is in blue (see the figure below).

Here is my test code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy

ytdist = np.array([662., 877., 255., 412., 996., 295., 468., 268.,
                    400., 754., 564., 138., 219., 869., 669.])
Z = hierarchy.linkage(ytdist, 'single')
hierarchy.set_link_color_palette(['k', 'k', 'k', 'k', 'k'])
dn = hierarchy.dendrogram(Z)
plt.show()
```

[image]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258428/coloring-labels-and-lines-in-a-dendrogram-plot) is a question that should address this problem, but I could not understand it very clearly.

Any hints or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way would be to set a `color_threshold` at `0` and then set the `above_threshold_color` to `'k'`, like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy

ytdist = np.array([662., 877., 255., 412., 996., 295., 468., 268.,
                    400., 754., 564., 138., 219., 869., 669.])
Z = hierarchy.linkage(ytdist, 'single')
dn = hierarchy.dendrogram(Z, color_threshold=0, above_threshold_color='k')
plt.show()
```

[image: Monocolor Dendrogram]

Comment: Thanks! That's precisely what I need! I was not aware of the color_threshold and  above_threshold_color parameters in function dendrogram(). Cheers.